# What is a good way in Mercurial to untrack all files and start fresh?

Tags: mercurial, text-processing

Related question:
 https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/275310/why-isnt-the-addremove-recommended-by-default-in-mercurial

I am working on a LaTeX project and was new to `Hg` when I started on it about a week ago. Basically I tracked all the files in the folder using the command `hg addremove *`. After realizing my error, I have been tracking only the files which I think I will repeatedly edit. However, I haven't yet untracked all the files I asked `Hg` to track at the start of the repo.

The result is that `Hg` not only tracks the source files with `.tex` extensions but is also tracking the resulting `.pdf` files — something that I think is resulting in an unnecessary bloat in my repo. How can I start fresh?

On a related but separate note: is it a bad idea to track MS Word files (say ending in `.docx`) using `Hg`?  My method of using LaTeX is somewhat like this: 
 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61967/how-to-run-latex-from-word
 
If add a string `Rome was not built in a day.` to a text file and save it, the new version of the text file is just 28 characters larger than the old version. I am not sure if `.docx` works in a similar way. Hence the question.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go. This holds also for other SCM systems.

Comment: I believe so. There are already a number of migration votes on the question, so you can either wait or you can delete the question here and ask again on SO.

Answer (score 1):

*Regarding your first question*

`hg convert` is what you're looking for -- [ConvertExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension).

You want to use the `--filemap` option to exclude all your PDF files.

Because the filemap doesn't support wildcards/globs (`*.pdf`), you'll need to build a list of all the PDF files in your repository in order to exclude them. If you're on a unix like platform you can do that with `find`.

Comment: `hg files -I '**/*.pdf'` should also list all PDF files tracked by Mercurial.